# How can I reuse studs?

Tags: studs

I know That it is probably impossible but I used a drill bit that is too big and the screws come out when I put a triangle bracket on it plus a small amount of weight.  I am wall mounting a desk and the amount of wieght that the bracket is supporting is much more than the weight that pulled it out.  I have been thinking of using wood glue but heard that it can be madw worse a with the use of it.  I am wall mounting a desk so changing bracket height is a last resort.

Comment: Are you saying that the pilot hole is too large for the screws you're using?  If that's the case, why not just use larger screws?

Comment: The screws barely fit through the bracket as is, I might be able to get screws with stupidly long fins through.

Comment: Sometimes it is easy to drill larger diameter holes in the bracket to accommodate larger screws. You may want to consider that anyway because it is not uncommon that screws provided with a bracket are hopelessly undersized tor any decent load holding power.

Answer (score 1):

Consider searching for "wood anchor bolts". Something [like this](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/fasteners/Threaded-Inserts/thread-inserts-for-wood/1-4-20-insert-for-soft-wood-flanged-901420-13?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjw5MGxBRDiuZm2icXX2-sBEiQA619bqzBCMcZ9zYug-6dVYxS0SDNckAJyqilTWkZvB00jSjUaAida8P8HAQ) might work for you, essentially providing a *machine screw* threaded hole in the stud for you to screw your bracket to.

EDIT: "threaded wood inserts" appears to be a good search term, too -- it finds [more like this](http://www.ezlok.com/online-catalog/inserts-for-wood/soft-wood-inserts/hex-drive).